# Badge for tag top answerer

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Specific tag "Top users" chart include a list of last 30 days top answerers. How about earning a badge for some amount of days spent as a top answerer on particular tag?

Answer (score 15):

If you spend long enough at the top of a tag you're likely to get the bronze, silver and gold badges for that tag anyway... do we really want any more than that?

Comment: I think this depends on specific tag popularity and amount of questions asked for that tag.

Comment: @yojimbo87: And that's the way it should be... would you want someone to get a badge for being "top" in a tag which only has a single question for example?

Comment: There could be some kind of limit which defines minimum amount of up votes which top answerer needs to have in order to earn this badge.

Comment: @yojimbo87: At which point, it's sounding more and more like the existing tag badges...