# New badge idea: Relentless

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

**Awarded to users who managed to keep at the top contributors** of a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) for the *Last 30 Days* for 30 straight days, **while earning at least** 30 upvotes in that tag, during the last 30 days.

It can be awarded multiple times (but only once per tag), and the amount of upvotes and the class of the badge is up for discussion.

Ex: if [Eggs McLaren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren) stays at the top for 30 days straight, but it's not able to earn at least 30 upvotes in that tag, he doesn't get the badge.

The original idea is to award the badge **only for the user who stays at the 1st position** of the list (higher score), for 30 days.

Comment: Now the question is, how do you deal with the occasional viral question that produces 500+ upvotes in one month? Should a minimum answer count be added? This has happened to me twice in the C++ tag.

Comment: And should it be applied retroactively? (I shamelessly say YES!)

Comment: If you're amenable to a name change, this seems like sort of the opposite of Generalist, so perhaps it could be called Specialist?

Comment: @Mysticial Interesting question. I think that a limit of at least 10 answers could be added.

Comment: 30 upvotes in the last 30 days is good for the less popular tags, but for many of the top tags *everyone* in the last 30 days leaderboard would get it.

Comment: It's just for the individual at the TOP. Just the highest score, not all of them.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now.

Comment: @PopularDemand Sounds interesting, but I think this badge invokes challenge, since you will be competing with the TOP guys at the tag to remain at the top, so I'm still voting for *Relentless*. But the community can suggest this name change in an answer and we can vote for it as well.

Comment: This could be applied retroactively. This happened to several badges already.

Comment: Hey look, a dupe. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87014/badge-for-tag-top-answerer One that's painfully vague, though.

Comment: Just from a technical standpoint: we don't track this data, and it would be *quite* expensive to do so (really hard to justify for only a badge)...I can't say that I see this happening.

Comment: @BoltClock: But I agree with Jon's answer from that question. This badge really isn't needed.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, but it's quite vague indeed. Glad to hear Mr. Skeet might be interested in this thread.

Comment: @animuson: Same here (but I guess [I'm biased](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-selectors/topusers)).

Comment: @animuson This idea has a much more limited scope and reward mechanism. There will be no silver/gold Relentless badges, I think bronze is just fine. On a side note, I think Jon Skeet is sick of getting any kind of badges. I am not! =D

Comment: How many upvotes are needed until the moderators decide it would be cool to get this implemented? I'm not convinced this question should be closed as a duplicate. I agree that these questions have some similarity due to the suggestion of a new badge using the same statistical mechanism of the site, however, **we propose using this mechanism and awarding the badge in different ways.**

Answer (score 6):

Expanding my comments to an answer.

I agree with this proposal, but there are a few issues that may need to be addressed first.

**Viral Questions:**

They happen about once or twice a month and often accumulate 500+ votes. This will likely shoot the answerer to the top of the list for every single tag on the question.

(It's happened to me twice... I wouldn't mind the badges, but would I really deserve them?)

So as you suggested in the comments, placing a minimum answer count would prevent a one-time answerer from getting the badge and will prevent an avid user from getting it in all the minor tags that were on the question.

**Retags:**

What if the question gets retagged? Should we revoke the badge? What if someone retags several question to the same tag to push a particular month over the limit?

Is this considered abuse?

**Might be impossible (for mortals) to get in some tags:**

Hmm... think C#, Java, etc... You know what I mean.

Comment: About **retags**, this is not a new problem. It's a problem we always had and we always will, and have been influencing other badges as well,  like Generalist. About being **impossible**, the purpose is to be challenging. :) But I think in the end this should be a bronze badge.

Comment: Getting to the top of a list is actually still very hard. Even if you stay clear of Jon Skeet's territory and go into something like C or C++ (where there's a bit more diversity in the top users), I've only done it once without the help of a viral question. So a bronze badge might not be "enough".

Comment: I agree with the concern about viral questions.  I'd love to see this implemented with a minimum question requirement, just like existing tag-based badges.

Comment: The C++ tag badges are becoming more obtainable as [top users continue to drop like flies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126319/suspension-request).